# Can you play h.264 saved in Dropbox on iOS?

Tags: iphone, video

I want to save h.264 video files on dropbox and play them on iPhone. Can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work. According to [this article](http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/97961), it works on the iPhone 4. I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work on iOS. Although, if it does not work, you can use [this](http://videoconverterapp.com/) iOS app that converts formats of files you transfer from PC to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Working fine with an M4V, AVC1 encoded file

Testing with mkv avc & mov apco…

… tested - no issues with mkv/avc or mov/apco either.